# Javascript: Show/hide elements based on their class

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I am including bilingual functionality on a website I am building. Researching the options I've gone for using the show/hide approach as I understand this is better for SEO, compared to switching out strings. I would also like to stick to javascript for now as I am still learning. I've gone over several posts here in StackOverflow, but have not found a solution so far.

The below approach works with a simple test file I have created, but once I try to implement it on the website it shows both languages in `onload` as well as when clicking the button. I'm working just with the Menu and a header of the page for now – maybe there is something I need to with these more specific elements?

My Html

```
(…)
<ul id="navlinks">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="lang-de"><a href="angebot.html">Angebot</a></li>
   <li class="lang-eng"><a href="angebot.html" class="thispage">Services</a></li>
   <li class="lang-de"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html" class="thispage">Über Uns</a></li>
   <li class="lang-eng"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html">About Us</a></li>
   <li class="thispage lang-de"><a href="beispiele.html">Beispiele</a></li>
   <li class="thispage lang-eng"><a href="beispiele.html">Beispiele</a></li>
   <li class="lang-de"><a href="rezensionen.html">Rezensionen</a></li>
   <li class="lang-eng"><a href="rezensionen.html">Reviews</a></li>
   <li class="lang-de"><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="lang-eng"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
(…)
<input type="button" value="Display Page in English" id="translate">
(…)
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/translate.js"></script>
```

My Javascript

```
var trans_button = document.getElementById("translate");
        var de = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-de"); //get all German text blocks
        var eng = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-eng"); // get all English text blocks
        var aufDeutsch = true;

//figure out which language should be visible
function translate() {
    if (aufDeutsch) {
        de.forEach(showObject);
        eng.forEach(hideObject);
        trans_button.textContent = "Display Page in English";
        aufDeutsch = false;
    } else {
        de.forEach(hideObject);
        eng.forEach(showObject);
        trans_button.textContent = "Diese Seite auf Deutsch zeigen";//SOLUTION: Change *TextContent* to *value*
        aufDeutsch = true;
    }
    console.log(de.length, eng.length, aufDeutsch);
    
}
        //hide the object
        function hideObject(item) {
            if(item.classList.contains('lang-active')) {
                item.classList.remove('lang-active'); 
            
            item.classList.add('lang-inactive');
            }
        }
        
        //shoe the object
        function showObject(item) {
            if(item.classList.contains('lang-inactive')) {
               item.classList.remove('lang-inactive'); 
            }
            item.classList.add('lang-active');
        }
        
        window.onload = translate; //set the correct language as the page loads
        trans_button.addEventListener("click", translate, false); //click listener to make the changes
```

My CSS

```
(…)
lang-active {
    display: block;
}
lang-inactive {
    display: none;
}
(…)
```

I have debugged through my browser (Safari). Javascript is collecting the array for each language correctly and exchanging the active/inactive class as well. I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but I'm just not seeing it. I've already tried to use `display: inherit` for the `lang-active` class. Also, the text in the button does not change when clicking.
As mentioned when I do this with a test-file (using paragraphs `<p>`) it all works.

//ETA: solved button text issue: I needed to change its value not its textContent.

Comment: `function hideObject(item) {
            if(item.classList.contains('lang-active')) {
                item.classList.remove('lang-active'); 
            
            item.classList.add('lang-inactive');
            }
        }
        

        function showObject(item) {
            if(item.classList.contains('lang-inactive')) {
               item.classList.remove('lang-inactive'); 
            }
            item.classList.add('lang-active');
        }` can be written `function toggle(item) { item.classList.toggle("lang-inactive")}`

Comment: thanks that definitely simplifies it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be VASTLY simplified

```js
let de,en, aufDeutsch = true;
const translate = function(e) {
  de.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle("lang-inactive", !aufDeutsch));
  en.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle("lang-inactive", aufDeutsch));
  e.target.textContent = aufDeutsch ? "Display Page in English" : "Diese Seite auf Deutsch zeigen";
  aufDeutsch = !aufDeutsch;
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  de = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang-de")]; //get all German text blocks
  en = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang-eng")]; // get all English text blocks
  const but = document.getElementById("translate")
  but.addEventListener("click", translate)
  but.click()
})
```

```css
.lang-inactive {
  display: none;
}

li { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<ul id="navlinks">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="lang-de"><a href="angebot.html">Angebot</a></li>
  <li class="lang-eng"><a href="angebot.html" class="thispage">Services</a></li>
  <li class="lang-de"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html" class="thispage">Über Uns</a></li>
  <li class="lang-eng"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="thispage lang-de"><a href="beispiele.html">Beispiele</a></li>
  <li class="thispage lang-eng"><a href="beispiele.html">Examples</a></li>
  <li class="lang-de"><a href="rezensionen.html">Rezensionen</a></li>
  <li class="lang-eng"><a href="rezensionen.html">Reviews</a></li>
  <li class="lang-de"><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="lang-eng"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<button id="translate">Translate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to simplify. Unfortunately, both issues still persist when I implement the change in the website code. I'll dig a little deeper into my CSS as there might be something hindering the display-change to take hold higher up in the hierarchy. But I stumped as to why the button text won't change.

Comment: button changed solved – I needed to change the value, not the text-content. (see original post). Still digging around for the show/hide

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `if` conditions inside the `hideObject` and `showObject` functions.

```js
 var trans_button = document.getElementById("translate");
        var de = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-de"); //get all German text blocks
        var eng = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-eng"); // get all English text blocks
        var aufDeutsch = true;

//figure out which language should be visible
function translate() {
    if (aufDeutsch) {
        de.forEach(showObject);
        eng.forEach(hideObject);
        trans_button.textContent = "Display Page in English";
        aufDeutsch = false;
    } else {
        de.forEach(hideObject);
        eng.forEach(showObject);
        trans_button.textContent = "Diese Seite auf Deutsch zeigen";
        aufDeutsch = true;
    }
    
}
        //hide the object
        function hideObject(item) {
            item.classList.remove('lang-active'); 
            item.classList.add('lang-inactive');
        }
        
        //shoe the object
        function showObject(item) {
               item.classList.remove('lang-inactive'); 
               item.classList.add('lang-active');
               }
        
        window.onload = translate; //set the correct language as the page loads
        trans_button.addEventListener("click", translate, false);
```

```css
.lang-active {
    display: block;
}
.lang-inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navlinks">
   <il><a href="index.html">Home</a></il>
   <il class="lang-de"><a href="angebot.html">Angebot</a></il>
   <il class="lang-eng"><a href="angebot.html" class="thispage">Services</a></il>
   <il class="lang-de"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html" class="thispage">Über Uns</a></il>
   <il class="lang-eng"><a href="wer_wir_sind.html">About Us</a></il>
   <il class="thispage lang-de"><a href="beispiele.html">Beispiele</a></il>
   <il class="thispage lang-eng"><a href="beispiele.html">Beispiele</a></il>
   <il class="lang-de"><a href="rezensionen.html">Rezensionen</a></il>
   <il class="lang-eng"><a href="rezensionen.html">Reviews</a></il>
   <il class="lang-de"><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></il>
   <il class="lang-eng"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></il>
</ul>
<button id="translate">Translate</button>
```

Comment: I first had it like that (without the if clause). When doing this within the website, I got an error as I was removing something from the ClassList during ```onload``` that didn't exist.

Comment: For that, make sure that the script is executed only after the page is fully loaded. Either include the `script` tag at the end of `body` element or execute the code after `DOMContentLoaded`  event is triggered.

Comment: Aha! Moving the ```script```outside of the body did the trick there (before it was still in the div-wrapper of the body), so I can remove that if-clause. Thanks for pointing that out. However, both the above issues still persist (both languages are displayed and button-text is not changed).